# Folder recovery with rm command

Tags: recovery-mode, rm

I deleted `/bin` folder from computer in Ubuntu with `rm` command.
How can recover it ?

Comment: If this answer is right for you, please mark answer as "accepted".

Answer (score 2):

Reinstall your system from a live session. Mount the partitions without formatting them;that will preserve your setting and files.

Mind though that it is wise to create a backup of your personal files from the live session before doing this.

And stop using "rm" in combination with "sudo" or a root session and evaluate why you feel the need. There should not be a reason to remove any file in the base of the system. If you installed software in the base system don't do that (use /opt/) or use the correct tool to remove them (like apt purge or apt remove).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. please explain, how can reinstall from live session

Comment: Same way you installed Ubuntu originally? Boot from the live session USB stick, follow the install procedure. Only thing you need to do is MOUNT the partition as you use them now and NOT format them.